# Pixel GUI File Manager question

Tags: pixel

I'm very new to RPi's, I'm trying to use it as a desktop. Recently got a WDPidrive 1TB. I want to use this Pi and HDD to store music files and pictures. Took me awhile to figure out where I could store the files on the HDD. Finally was able to store about 250GB of music and pictures. Audacous works great. So I didn't have to go far, I bookmarked the files location via File Manager on the Pixel GUI. But then decide to rearrange things and delete some. The old bookmarks remain even though they always return an error. So how do I get rid of these obsolete book marks? Where is this info stored so I can delete it?
BTW the WD 1 TB Pi drive is OK but the documentation is very weak. Lots of wasted hours figuring it out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File manager bookmarks, how to delete obsolete ones?](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/61620/file-manager-bookmarks-how-to-delete-obsolete-ones)

Comment: Ok, magically a new file showed up in File Manager called .gtk-bookmarks which I edited to delete the 2 offending obsolete bookmarks. Thanks much. Very nice. Now I know for future.